# Evaluating $\displaystyle\lim_{x\space\to\space0} \frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^{x} \frac{t^3\ln(1-t)}{t^4 + 4}\,dt$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{x\space\to\space0} \frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^{x}
>  \frac{t^3\ln(1-t)}{t^4 + 4}\,dt$$

Any advice on how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried L'Hopital?

Comment: Combining the fundamental theorem of calcul and L'Hopital as Arian commented seems to be a good way.

Comment: @Arian I applied L'Hopital on it - and it seems to yield $\frac{1}{8}$ - I'm not sure if that is correct. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: Could you show your steps ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I made a silly calculation error - now it's yielding $ - \frac{1}{20}$ - and I think it's correct.

Comment: @Monk: I think your last result is correct.

Comment: Mistake on my side !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x}
>  \frac{t^3\ln(1-t)}{t^4 + 4}\,dt=
>  \frac{x^3\ln(1-x)}{x^4 + 4}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\space\to\space0} \dfrac{1}{x^5}\int_0^{x}\dfrac{t^3\ln(1-t)}{t^4 + 4}\,dt&=\lim_{x\space\to\space0} \frac{1}{5x^4}\cdot
 \frac{x^3\ln(1-x)}{x^4 + 4}\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{x\space\to\space0}
 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{(5x)(x^4 + 4)}\\
&=\lim_{x\space\to\space0}
 -\frac{\ln(1-x)}{-x}\cdot\frac{1}{5(x^4 + 4)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{20}\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\lim_{x\space\to\space0} \frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^{x}
>  \frac{t^3\ln(1-t)}{t^4 + 4}\,dt=-\frac{1}{20}$$

---

Explanation : $(1)$ Use L'Hopital's Rule

Comment: @Monk So... which limit do you get?

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{t^3\ln(1-t)}{t^4+4}=\frac{t^3}{t^4+4}(-t-\frac{t^2}2...)=-\frac{t^4}4+o(t^4),$$
and integrating,
$$-\frac{x^5}{20}+o(x^5).$$

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $t =  xu$, we get
$$\int_0^x dt \frac{t^3 \log{(1-t)}}{t^4+4} = x^4 \int_0^1 du \frac{u^3 \log{(1-x u)}}{4+x^4 u^4} $$

so the limit is,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x}\int_0^1 du \frac{u^3 \log{(1-x u)}}{4+x^4 u^4} =  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x}\int_0^1 du \frac{-x u^4}{4} = -\frac1{20}$$

Comment: @Integrator: My point was that, in problems like these, it makes sense to scale the limits of integration so as to remove the dependence on $x$ and bring that dependence inside the integral.  Then finding the limit is very easy.

Comment: @Integrator: Uhhh....integration by substitution?  Really, I have no link.  Just an arrow in my quiver.

Comment: @RonGordon Could you please explain this transformation $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x}\int_0^1 du \frac{u^3 \log{(1-x u)}}{4+x^4 u^4} =  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x}\int_0^1 du \frac{-x u^4}{4}$ ?

Comment: @Monk: Because $u \in [0,1]$, we can say that $x u \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.  Thus, $\log{(1-x u)} \sim - x u$ and $4+x^2 u^2 \to 4$ in this limit.

Comment: @RonGordon - wouldn't it be better to edit the answer to add that?