# GRE math question: $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x \frac{t + t^2}{1 + \sin t}\, \mathrm{d} t \right] $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, limits-without-lhopital

This question is from the Princeton Review book *Cracking the GRE Mathematics Subject Test*, chapter 2, question 7. The question asks to find the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \dfrac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x \dfrac{t + t^2}{1 + \sin t}\, \mathrm{d} t \right] $$

My solution was as follows: let $F(t)$ be some antiderivative of $(t + t^2)/(1 + \sin t)$. Then, the limit can be written

$\begin{align} \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \dfrac{1}{x^2} (F(x) - F(0)) \right] &= \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \cdot \dfrac{F(x) - F(0)}{x} \right] \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \cdot F'(0) \right] = 0 \end{align}$

However, the correct answer is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, as given here:

> Since the integral equals $0$ when $x = 0$, the limit is of the indeterminate form $\dfrac{0}{0}$, so we apply L'Hôpital's rule
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^x \dfrac{t + t^2}{1 + \sin t} \, dt}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\dfrac{x + x^2}{1 + \sin x}}{2x}$$
>
> $$ = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(1 + x)}{2x(1 + \sin x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 + x}{2(1 + \sin x)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

I understand the provided solution, but cannot see why my solution is incorrect?

Comment: Note the post from yesterday of [I'm having trouble solving $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x \frac{t + t^2}{1 + \sin(t)} dt$ (Pset 3, #8 of UCLA math gre practice problems)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3576675/602049) asks about solving this same problem.

Comment: You have made a typical error of replacing a part of expression by its limit while evaluating limit of a bigger expression. This is valid only under very specific circumstances. For instance your method would have worked if $F'(0)\neq 0$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031) for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$F'(0)$ does not equal $\dfrac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}$, but

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}$$

So (to use your way) you would have to split the limits, but then you get an undefined limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Note that the splitting would have worked fine if the derivative $F'(0)\neq 0$.